# Eclipse Switch focus to console on Run

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to learn Java using Eclipse (Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)).
I have run into this issue: everytime I Run my project the cursor stays in the "Editor window" (where I write all the code).
What I want it to do is to switch focus to the "Console Window" - so I can start typing in the console directly. (Right now I am forced to use my mouse and manually click on the Console Window - which is really annoying.)

Comment: They are both enabled. I can see the console at all times. I just want the focus to change to it when I Run my code.

Comment: If an answer below solves your problem then please Accept it so that appropriate credit is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change to a view with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, release keys, and then wait for a moment and you will get a pop-up of views to select:

[image]

If you then press  <kbd>C</kbd> the console will open. You don't have to wait for the pop-up if you don't want to.

If you want to change to the console often, perhaps a shorter key sequence.

In *Preferences* choose *General* -> *Keys*, then scroll or use filter to find *Show View (Console)* and you can change the shortcut:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the convenience you want, but try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: Note that you can change default shortcut.

Comment: alt+shift+q+c shows a pop-up window called "Change Method Signature". -I have no idea what that is or does.

Comment: Peter, it looks like you pressed Alt<+Shift+C, what you need to do is press Alt+Shift+Q then release and press C

Comment: Thank you for the edit and the added comment, Aleksandr!